# Missing number, treated as zero in TeXwors on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: errors, windows, linux

I'm writing something in Latex. Natively I'm using Linux/Ubuntu and it works. Now I'm trying to use the same file (no changes) on my Windows with MikTex.

As GUI I use Texworks.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: this is highly unlikely to be caused by a difference in the operating system but by a different version of one of the packages used, but as you have given no indication about your input document or the error that you got, then it's not possible to help. Add `\listfiles` to your document and then compare the list of package versions at the end of the log file in the two systems.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done that and I found out, that almost all used packages are newer on Windows, than on Linux. For Example: Windows uses titlesec 2.13 and Linux uses titlesec 2.10.2